# I downloaded the android source, no build processing, so how do I build it?

Tags: android

I create a new Android project, and then Android music source AndroidManifest.xml, src, res file copied to the new project, but there was a mistake

```
F:\projcet0301\Music3\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(601, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/colorAccent').
Error:(601, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/colorAccent').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: You don't have to download *the android source* (I assume AOSP) to build and app (I assume is your intention)

Comment: e,I download google music app source , but no build processing